# propabilities very simple problem

Tags: probability

Let's assume we have a total of 6,000,000 voters (6m samples-people) out of 20,000,000 people having the right to vote (66% absence). 9% of the voters choose "party a" and the rest 91% choose other parties. 
How can I calculate the outs of meeting two random people in the street, voting for party a, in a town with a population of 100,000?

Its pretty simple, but my brain has shut down. Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Can be the two random people children ?

Comment: You are right, i didn't mention that the random people are having the right to vote, so is the population of 100k as well.

Comment: The probability, that the first voter votes for party a is 9%. And the probabiliy, that the second voter votes for party a is $9\%\cdot 100,000-1$ divided by $100,000$. You have to multiply both probabilities. This is approximately $0.09\cdot 0.09=0.0081$

Comment: But aren't we supposed to include the absence percentage as well?